# Select from two or more sql tables where have some column names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli

I have 6 table where all columns name is same. Now I want to select only those table where new = '1'.

For example:

```
Table 1: 3d_movie
+----+------+-----+------+
| id | name | new | date |
+----+------+-----+------+
|  1 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|
|  2 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|
|  3 |name2 | 1   | 10.00|
+----+------+-----+------+

Table 2: english_movie
+----+------+-----+------+
| id | name | new | date |
+----+------+-----+------+
|  1 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|
|  2 |name1 | 1   | 10.00|
|  3 |name2 | 0   | 10.00|
+----+------+-----+------+

Table 3: hindi_movie
+----+------+-----+------+
| id | name | new | date |
+----+------+-----+------+
|  1 |name1 | 1   | 10.00|
|  2 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|
|  3 |name2 | 0   | 10.00|
+----+------+-----+------+
```

When admin add a new movie on his server, he select new = 1.
So if client go to new movies page, I want to search all movie from all table where new = '1'.

I tried by these way but it's not work, please help me..

```
Tried 1: $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM 3d_movie,english_movie,hindi_movie WHERE 3d_movie.new='1' and english_movie.new='1' and hindi_movie.new='1 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30");

Tried 2: $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM 3d_movie,english_movie,hindi_movie WHERE new='1' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30");
```

Comment: You are looking for `UNION`; but if it is not too late I would change your table structure. You should not need 6 tables that are identical in all but name; instead make one table and add one or more columns to distinguish the contents that would've gone in different tables. For a primitive example: a "type" string in which you store strings like "3d", "english", "hindi"; a better example would be a `movie_types` table that the `movies` table references (through a `movie_movie_types` table) in a `many-to-many` relationship, allowing you to represent a movie that is both "hindi" AND "3d".

Comment: you first one fails because if only one table gets a 'new' record, the others will have NO new records and return nothing, because `and` requires that the conditions be true in ALL checks, not just one. perhaps you want `or` instead. But even then, you're doing a cartesian product join of the tables, and you'll get all kinds of wonky results. the 2nd one fails because 'new' is not a unique identifier.

Comment: Also, why are there `date` fields that hold decimal values???

Comment: Why dont you add a `movie_type` or `category` column in your table and keep only one table?

Comment: Yes. movie type/category/genre is good suggestion. I will do it, but its too late. Thank you so much all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to frame a SQL query using `UNION`. Try the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM 3D_MOVIE
WHERE NEW = 1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM ENGLISH_MOVIE
WHERE NEW = 1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM HINDI_MOVIE
WHERE NEW = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Select using UNION

```
SELECT *
FROM 3d_movie
WHERE new = 1

UNION

SELECT *
FROM 3d_movie
WHERE new = 1
```

and so on

That is the easiet way, but in the future you should consider combining the tables and adding one column do identify the movie genre:

```
Table 1: movie
+----+------+-----+------+-------+
| id | name | new | date | genre |
+----+------+-----+------+-------+
|  1 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|  3d   |
|  2 |name1 | 0   | 10.00|  eng  |
|  3 |name2 | 1   | 10.00|  hin  |
+----+------+-----+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run SQL query among your tables to get your desired output. However, better solution to your problem would be if you can change your table structure. Rather than keeping multiple tables you can simply add another column like `moview_type` or `category` and put all movie list in the same table. So your table will look like the below:

```
+----+------+-----+------+----------+
| id | name | new | date | category |
+----+------+-----+------+----------+
|  1 |name1 | 0   | 10.00| 3d       |
|  2 |name1 | 0   | 10.00| English  |
|  3 |name2 | 1   | 10.00| Hindi    |
+----+------+-----+------+----------+
```

This way you do not have to add new tables if you have a new types of movie.